# Image upload to FTP issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using the following code to upload a image to my FTP server but I have a problem. If I use the code to check the dimension (height and width) of the image before upload then there is .png file created in the FTP server but it's empty (or invalid format) and if I remove the code to check the dimension, then the image is uploaded correctly. Does any have any idea on this?

```
    public ActionResult UploadFile(int type, HttpPostedFileBase imagefile)
    {
        //check image height and width
        using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imagefile.InputStream, true, true))
        {
            if (image.Width > 160 || image.Height > 160)
            {
                //do something here
            }
        }//end check image height and width

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftpPath" + "/" + imagefile.FileName);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpUserName", "ftpPassword");

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        var sourceStream = imagefile.InputStream;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        request.ContentLength = sourceStream.Length;
        int BUFFER_SIZE = imagefile.ContentLength;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        do
        {
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        } while (bytesRead > 0);
        sourceStream.Close();
        requestStream.Close();
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
}
```

Comment: When you call `FromStream` you consume the `InputStream`, causing it to be at the end of the stream. Thus, when you read it later, there is nothing left to read. You need to reset the stream to the beginning, or read everything to a byte array and create a separate stream from that.

Comment: Did you mean to write "uploaded incorrectly" instead of "uploaded correctly"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the reply they were very helpful but I fixed this issue by making slight changes on my code as below, I checked the image dimension after reading the input Stream. May be someone find this helpful.

```
public string ftpUpload(HttpPostedFileBase imagefile, string filename)
        {
            var sourceStream = imagefile.InputStream;
            int BUFFER_SIZE = imagefile.ContentLength;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

            if (!CheckLogoDimension(sourceStream))
            {
                sourceStream.Close();
                return "error";
            }

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpRootPath + "/" + filename);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserName, ftpPassword);

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            request.ContentLength = sourceStream.Length;
            do
            {
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            } while (bytesRead > 0);
            sourceStream.Close();
            requestStream.Close();
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();

            return "Success";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you are reading up all the stream when you load it into your `Image`.  However, I don't think you can reset the position (i.e. "Seek") on a NetworkStream (your `InputStream`). Once you read it, it is gone.

One thing you can do though is to create a `MemoryStream` and use `Stream.CopyTo` to copy the contents into that. Then, you can do anything you like with it, including resetting the position to 0 to "read it a second time".

```
//example of resetting a stream named "s"
s.Position = 0;
```